# Calculating the average magnitude of an array of doubles containing n elements

Tags: c

I am trying to calculate the average magnitude of an array of doubles.

sample array is `double samples[] = { 5.7, 2.3, -1.9, 4.5, 6.2, -8.1, 9.7, 3.1 };`

and my function is:

```
double avg_magnitude(double x[], double n){

double mag, sum;

for(int i = 0; i < n) {
    sum += fabs(x[i]);
    i++;
}
mag = sum / n;
return mag;
}
```

function returns a value of 6.19 instead of the correct value of 5.19

Comment: Why do you instantiate `i` twice and not `mag` or `sum` (i.e. `mag = 0.0;` and `sum = 0.0;`)?

Comment: Turn on all compiler warnings to find the error. Spoiler: You are not initializing `sum` to zero.

Comment: the two i variables was a typo moving the function over to SO. @AndreasWenzel solution for initializing sum to zero fixed the problem, thank you

Comment: I beleive `for(int i = 0; i < n)` is a syntax error, I think it needs to be `for(int i = 0; i < n;)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `double sum` is allocated from the stack and is assigned a garbage value. Make sure to initialize your local variables.

```
double avg_magnitude(double x[], double n){
    double mag=0.0, sum=0.0;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        sum += fabs(x[i]);
    }
    mag = sum / n;
    return mag;
}
```

Also make sure to compile using the argument `-Wall` to get notified by errors like these.